# Get in depth information about vulnerability from a CVE

Tags: exploit, cve, exploit-development, research

I'm trying to understand how to get more information about a vulnerability given a CVE. I noticed that some CVEs, on websites like https://www.cvedetails.com, have got references to articles or to code, for example a reference to https://www.exploit-db.com, sometimes you can find code on Github from the author or even a metasploit module. It seems to me that many CVEs, if not the majority, have got just a small description of the problem (something like an "abstract") and references to advisories or patches, with no information about the vulnerability itself. How can I know more about a vulnerability in this case? I suppose there's some research behind a CVE, so I should be able to find a research paper somewhere, right?

For example, that's the case of [CVE-2017-3167](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2017-3167):

- There's no exploit-db entry and no metasploit module
- I can't find any code in Github
- I can't find any real article that talks about it
- I can't find any publication on Google Scholar
- I can't even find author's name!

It makes sense to me that, for security reasons, there's no code available for this particular vulnerability because it's classified as `CRITICAL`, but I think a better, theoretical, description of the vulnerability should be available for learning/research purposes. So maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all CVE's have a public detailed technical disclosure and especially not all CVE's have a public working exploit.
However, there are some ways to identify the technical details behind a CVE:

- Check Git changes - Some CVE's are related to open source software and so the patch can be publicly available in the Git history of the project.
- Check functionality changes - CVE's may effect functionality, being able to detect the change in functionality can lead to an assumption of what the vulnerability is.
- Reverse engineer - Taking a look at the disassembled code, network traffic or anything else related to the software can help get a better understanding of the patch. This is assuming you can compare the software before and after the patch.

I have found that most information I can get related to a CVE is from the National Vulnerability Database (NVD). For example, the CVE you mentioned can be found [here](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2017-3167). A full search can be found [here](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/search/results?form_type=Basic&results_type=overview&query=CVE-2017-3167&search_type=all&isCpeNameSearch=false).

Comment: Using your approach, I identified [this commit](https://github.com/apache/httpd/commit/92ab67cbad4e148c4ed97bba713e7b320a4412f9) where they deprecate the old function and create a new, secure, one! Thank you!